# Is there a non-katakana word for "cash flow"?

Tags: word-choice, loanwords, business-japanese

If you look up "cash flow" in most dictionaries, it seems the concept is expressed in katakana, `キャッシュフロー`.

However, I was speaking with a Japanese person earlier, and the term was not immediately understood. I ended up having to explain in a roundabout way that I was referring to my income and outflow of cash, and how it effected the amount I had available at one time.

Two questions:

Is `キャッシュフロー` not in common use by everyone?

In any case, is there a clearer native Japanese term I can use to express the same concept?

Comment: 現金流量 is the japanese word you are looking for dixit wikipedia http://goo.gl/lcO3Q

Comment: @Dave M G Could you give an example sentence how you used the word `キャッシュフロー` ?

Comment: OMG I am so ignorant that I don't know キャッシュフロー or even 現金流量...

Comment: I wonder who ever uses 現金流量…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with 'cashflow' in English is that it has a business meaning (which I think is income generated from a business or investment) and a colloquial meaning (referring to liquidity or general financial situation).

If you're looking for an equivalent to the business term, I think キャッシュフロー is probably ok. But if you're just trying to refer to your impecuniousness in a mock-business sort of way, you should look for something else. キャッシュフロー hasn't made it into ordinary Japanese vocabulary in the same way that 'cashflow' has in English. I might suggest 金銭状態 as a possible equivalent, but there are probably snappier and more appropriate ways of saying it.

Note: I just thought of the expression 金回り, which might also fit the bill -- although 金回り could suggest a rather more serious situation than the casual use of 'cashflow' would imply. At any rate, this page (http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E9%87%91%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8A) gives a lot of interesting synonyms for 金回り that might be useful:

1. 個人・会社などの金回り
   収支 ・ 財政状態 ・ ふところ具合 ・ 台所事情 ・ 金繰り ・ 資金繰り ・ 金融（調査） ・ （金の）流れ
2. 金回りがよい
   羽振りがよい ・ 金がうなっている ・ 潤っている ・ 金持ち ・ バブル（紳士） ・ 潤沢な資金をもつ～
3. 金回りがよくない
   経済的苦境（にある） ・ 手元不如意 ・ しけている ・ 苦しい ・ （台所は）火の車 ・ 金欠病 ・ 金詰まり

Comment: +1 for "impecuniousness".

Answer (score 8):

You could use `収支【しゅうし】` (which is a contraction of `収入【しゅうにゅう】` and `支出【ししゅつ】`).  It means "earnings and expenses", which is basically the same as "cash flow".  Although it's not informal like "cash flow", so if you are looking for something informal or slang-y, this wouldn't be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

キャッシュフローis rather formal and isn't used in everyday conversation I think.

maybe you could consider using 家計

not sure tho

Comment: But of course, 家計 is for 家計. You won't be using that for business cashflow, but I figure my heart will feel a bit warm if I can get one business to use it.